# Does "the likes of" usually have a pejorative connotation?

Tags: phrase-usage, connotations

Does the sentence

> I admire heroes the likes of Batman and Superman.

sound wrong? Because I usually hear *the likes of* in sentences such as

> Don't compare me to the like(s) of you!

But according to [The Free Dictionary](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/the+likes+of)'s definition of *the likes of*, it means

> someone or something as good as someone or something else

and the two sentences it gives are

> We haven't seen the likes of Muhammad Ali since he retired from the ring.
>
> They're not competing against the likes of you or me but real, first-class, serious athletes.

Does *the likes of* carry a pejorative connotation like in the second TFD sentence? Or is it really commonly used in the manner of the first TFD sentence (and my first sentence)?

Comment: Shouldn't this be asked on http://english.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The phrase 'the likes of' has a pejorative connotation fairly often, but not always.  But the phrase always draws attention to a stark difference between the speaker (or "us") and the person(s) spoken about or spoken to, or between the person or thing spoken about and other persons (or things) to whom he or she (or it) might be compared.

**He had a great baritone voice. We won't hear the likes of it again any time soon.**

**Why are you dating the likes of him? He's been in and out of juvy since he was 13.**

Consider [this review](https://books.google.com/books?id=RlIhAQAAIAAJ&dq=%22the%20likes%20of%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=y9-aVLvgBK_gsAT0q4H4Aw&ved=0CEcQ6AEwCA) of a collection of poetry called *The Likes of Us*, where the lines of the poems are compared to "shady characters" (shady=disreputable).

Wright's [English Dialect Dictionary](https://books.google.com/books?id=7Ks4AQAAMAAJ&pg=RA1-PA602&dq=%22the%20likes%20of%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=y9-aVLvgBK_gsAT0q4H4Aw&ved=0CG8Q6AEwDw#v=onepage&q=%22the%20likes%20of%22&f=false) shows examples of non-pejorative uses:

**It's all very well for the likes of you, but poor men can't afford it.**

There, the *difference* between the speaker and the person spoken to is being emphasized. "You" there is not a "shady character" but someone who has much more wealth than the speaker.

Answer (score 3):

As you can see from [this chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the%20like%20of%20him%2Cthe%20likes%20of%20him&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthe%20like%20of%20him%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthe%20likes%20of%20him%3B%2Cc0), originally it was normally singular ***like***...

[image]

The full OED lists this usage as...

> **the like(s) of (rarely to)**: *such a person or thing as;* now **often depreciatory**. colloq.

Those two observations seem to confirm my gut feel that if you encounter ***like*** rather than ***likes*** in such contexts, it's much more likely to be an *approving* reference (because the implication of OED's ***now*** often depreciatory is that it wasn't *originally* so).

When I read OP's example my first thought was that I'd probably have written *the **like** of Muhammad Ali*. But having just compared hits in Google Books for [the like of Churchill](https://www.google.co.uk/search?hl=en&source=hp&q=%22the%20likes%20of%20Muhammad%20Ali%22&aq=f&aqi=g5g-z1g4&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=&gws_rd=ssl#hl=en&q=%22the%20like%20of%20Churchill%22) (4430) and [the likes of Churchill](https://www.google.co.uk/search?hl=en&source=hp&q=%22the%20likes%20of%20Muhammad%20Ali%22&aq=f&aqi=g5g-z1g4&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=&gws_rd=ssl#hl=en&q=%22the%20likes%20of%20Churchill%22) (51,200) against [the like of Hitler](https://www.google.co.uk/search?hl=en&source=hp&q=%22the%20likes%20of%20Muhammad%20Ali%22&aq=f&aqi=g5g-z1g4&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=&gws_rd=ssl#hl=en&q=%22the%20like%20of%20Hitler%22) (16,500) and [the likes of Hitler](https://www.google.co.uk/search?hl=en&source=hp&q=%22the%20likes%20of%20Muhammad%20Ali%22&aq=f&aqi=g5g-z1g4&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=&gws_rd=ssl#hl=en&q=%22the%20likes%20of%20Hitler%22) (70,500) I'm no longer quite so sure. Obviously almost all the *first* pair will be positive, and almost all the second pair will be negative. But proportionately, Hitler gets the singular far more often than Churchill, which is the opposite of what I'd expect.

---

Note that the construction in *We shall not see **his like** again* is almost always positive (and rarely involves the plural). Also note that I've used the relatively formal ***shall not*** rather than colloquial ***won't*** there, to reflect the fact that ***his like/likes*** is a bit dated/poetic.

But with no further context I'd understand *We won't see **the like/likes of him** again* as "disapproving" regardless of plurality (speaker thinks they're [well shut of](https://www.phrases.org.uk/bulletin_board/51/messages/439.html) his sort / people like him).

Answer (score 0):

imagine the speaker standing with one hand showing "the teachers finger pointed up" and then shouting in a exited way:  "It is the likes of which" jada jada jada.....

well.... i guess it demands some extra attention, if that phrase appears from political leaders, formulating their reasons for division of people by saying...   its "the likes of which" (any worded reason variable here) who are the reason for (whatever other variable)....

i am sure thats the one case that was seen already a few times in history
(far past or recent), that causes that throat wrenching feeling and bitter taste at the same time, when that wording is used....

so yeah, in that particular context i say yes, there is a pejorative connotation...
somehow...

Comment: Can you edit to give a source for this usage as your answer is rather difficult to understand without it.